# Characters not appearing in my website (using utf-8)

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I am just learning how to code, so this may have an obvious solution, but I have searched for answers for a few days now. Several characters at the end of the alphabet (x,y,z, etc.) are not appearing in the actual website despite it appearing in my code. for example in HTML I will type

"Last year was my senior year"

and my website will say

"Last ear was m senior ear"

I have insured that I am using utf-8 (unicode) on both platforms and have re-written the code many times. Any help would be appreciated, and an image of the problem will be posted as well.

[html code on left, website on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnKU3.jpg)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: have you tried going to your devtools and check the elements at inspect element? does the elements there have the correct content?

Comment: Can you please share the actual HTML code in text form? Maybe it contains look-alike characters like [у (U+0443 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U)](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/0443) instead of a "real" [y (U+0079 LATIN SMALL LETTER Y)](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/0079)...

Comment: Please: do not include code as images: copy paste the real code in the question. In such manner we can test, and we can also copy part of it in the answer (help us to help you). (and it is also good practice not to open random links from random people). If you copy paste your sentence, copy also on an editor which allow you to see the code point , or transform it in ASCII and check if the string are equal (NOT by looking it, really binary equal). Check if you can print y,z in such font (maybe it is corrupt font file).

Answer (score 0):

In your software, you could try to look for a "Display invisible characters" preference, maybe there's one somewhere around the missing letter that is the cause of your issue?

I sometimes have such issues when I accidentally do a fine space (alt + space on Mac) rather than a normal space. That sounds impossible but actually happens when I write code too fast, when I insert a space after or before characters such as [] or {} that require using the alt key...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this seems to be a Google Chome/font problem: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2892761/the-letter-y-is-missing-on-some-pages-i-can-look-up-the-pages-in-another-browser-and-they-display-fine